# Spring Boot call a Rest Controller method from a service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring Boot to call a rest controller method from a service. When the method gets called, I get the error java.lang.NullPointerException The broad scenario is, my service receives a payload from RabbitMQ queue and extracts the contents of the payload which it should then pass to the controller to be saved into the database. The queue part works(I can receive messages from the queue and extract the contents). Also the database part works. The problem is calling the controller method from the service.

Here us my Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController implements AuthService {
    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    AuthRepository authRepository;


    public AuthModel addAuthenticatable(AuthModel auth){
        auth.setCreatedAt(DateTimeUtility.getDateTime());
        return authRepository.save(auth);
    }
}
```

My service code:

```
public class QueueListener extends AuthController implements MessageListener{
    private String identifier;
    private JSONArray globalObject;
    private int userId;
    private String pin;

    @Autowired
    AuthController authController;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        String msg = new String(message.getBody());
        String output = msg.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        String jsonified = output.substring(1, output.length()-1);

        JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(jsonified);
        this.globalObject = obj;
        this.identifier = obj.getJSONObject(0).getString("identifier");
        resolveMessage();
    }
    public void resolveMessage() {
        if(identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD_TO_AUTH")) {
            for(int i = 0; i < globalObject.length(); i++){ 
                JSONObject o = globalObject.getJSONObject(i);
                this.userId = Integer.parseInt(o.getString("userId"));
                this.pin = o.getString("pin");
            }

            AuthModel authModel = new AuthModel();
            authModel.setUserId(userId);
            authModel.setPin(pin);

            authController.addAuthenticatable(authModel);
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I call the method addAuthenticatable() which is in AuthController. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is QueueListener  a bean? do you have any annotation on top of this class?

Comment: There are no annotations on QueueListener.

Comment: Why should the QueueListener both extend and have a dependency on AuthController ? Please, reconsider the organization of your dependencies. Do you really want to inject a rest controller into the QueueListener? Or do you want some specific logic to be executed? You could extract the logic of the addAuthenticatable method into a service and inject the service for starters

Comment: What is this `AuthController implements AuthService and QueueListener extends AuthController again you are injecting AuthController in same class` is this correct implementation?

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou Probably its my design which is flawed (I'm still very green  in Spring - Especially the annotations part, What to annotate with what). How would you do it? I have the class which listens to messages from Rabbit and should call a controller method and pass a model to the controller for inserting to the DB. The Message part and the DB part I got it working well. My problem is passing the model to the controller from the listening class. How would you do it? And which annotations would you use on which classes? What would you Autowire? Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this does not go out of topic, but generally what we want to achieve is a sort of an onion architecture. The dependencies should have one direction.

Your controller is an integration point for your application. You want per REST to **trigger the execution** of some piece of logic. Your controller should not extend classes or implement interfaces, that have to do with the business logic. This part belongs to another layer.

Everything that is about logic belongs to services:

```
@Service
public class AuthService {
    @Autowired
    private AuthRepository authRepository;

    private String attribute;

    public boolean isAuthenticated(String username) {
        authRepository.doSomething();
        //implementation of the logic to check if a user is authenticated.
    }

   public boolean authenticate(String username, char[] password) {
       // implementation of logic to authenticate.
       authRepository.authenticate();
   }

   public AuthModel save(AuthModel model) {
       //implementation of saving the model
   }

}
```

Extracting your logic in the service layer, made things reusable.
Now you could inject the service in a `controller`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

   @Autowired
   private AuthService authService;

   public AuthModel addAuthenticatable(AuthModel auth){
       //process input etc..
       return authService.save(auth);
   }
}
```

or in a `amqListener`

```
@Component
public class QueueListener implements MessageListener {
   @Autowired
   private AuthService authService;

   @Autowired
   private SomeOtherService otherService;

   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message message) {
      JSONArray array = processInput();

      JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(jsonified);
      String identifier = obj.getJSONObject(0).getString("identifier");
      // extract the business logic to the service layer. Don't mix layer responsibilities
      otherService.doYourThing(obj, identifier);

      resolveMessage();
  }

  private JSONArray processInput(Message message) {
     String msg = new String(message.getBody());
     String output = msg.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
     String jsonified = output.substring(1, output.length()-1);


}
```

and your configuration, so that you can let spring know where to look for the annotated classes.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"your.service.packages"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "your.model.package")
@EnableJpaRepositories("your.repository.packages")
@EnableRabbit // probaby
@EnableWebMvc // probably
public class Config {
   //you could also define other beans here
   @Bean
   public SomeBean someBean() {
       return new SomeBean();
   }
}
```

@pvpkiran gave the answer to your actual question. But I hope this helps you

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your class QueueListener is not a spring bean. Hence all the variables that you have `@Autowired` will not be injected. Make it a spring bean using one of the Annotations, `@Service`, `@Component`.....

For example.

```
@Component
public class QueueListener extends AuthController implements MessageListener{
   .....
}
```

Cannot say this will solve your problem entirely(because of your super classes), because I don't have enough information. But I am sure it will get rid of NPE.

Comment: did you try to debug? when you call `authController.addAuthenticatable(authModel)` is authController is null or not?

Comment: authController is null

Comment: that means you class is not getting scanned by spring. make sure you have @Component annotation and also make sure you class is scanned by spring. check `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Which class should I annotate with @ComponentScan? The Listening class or AuthController?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to extend **and** autowire that controller. If you are going to extend, than there is no need to put dependencies in the extended class, this is just complicating the design. So either make the controller a dependency by autowiring it OR extend it (in which case there is no need for it to have dependencies).
When using `@Autowired` - make sure all your classes are properly annotated as suggested and that they are being scanned by your main application class.  There are some good practices that are recommended in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html).

**EDIT**
Controllers are annotated with `@Controller` and service classes with `@Service` which is basically a decorated `@Component` annotation. All of this is explained pretty well in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html), it is a great place to start exploring.

**Back to the question:**

If you are still getting a NPE, check your project structure, probably your class is not being picked up by spring's component scan or one of the classes is not anotated. Your main class (One that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) should be in the root/default package in order to scan all other `@Component`s.

Comment: I am confused (I am still green in Spring) with which classes to annotate with what. I have refactored to remove the extending part but still same problem. How should I pass data from a service class to a controller class? What should I annotate service class and controller class with? Which class should I Autowire and where?